# Calculation using Date function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to compute `TO_DATE` column for a group of `BINGID`, `INDUSID`, `COMP1`.

When `IsRowActive = 1` then `TO_DATE` = "9999-12-31" , which is being returned correctly.

But when `IsRowActive = 0`, then we have to calculate `To_Date` which should be 1 sec less than next `FROMDT`

Data :

```
    DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE

(
BINGID INT,
INDUSID INT,
DTSEARCH DATETIME2,
COMP1 VARCHAR (100),
LISTPRICE NUMERIC(10,2),
FROMDT DATETIME2,
IsRowActive INT

)
INSERT @MYTABLE

SELECT 1002285, 1002,   '2016-03-03 04:10:58.0000000',  '0026PU009163-031', '77.7600',  '2015-12-19 12:51:49.0000000',0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002,   '2016-05-27 12:14:53.0000000',  '0026PU009163-031', '85.2200',  '2016-05-27 12:14:53.0000000',0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002,   '2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000',  '0026PU009163-031', '90.3900',  '2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000',0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002,   '2016-11-09 13:37:13.0000000',  '0026PU009163-031', '131.4500', '2016-10-18 13:49:10.0000000',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002,   '2015-12-19 12:51:41.0000000',  '10122374', 65.1400,    '2015-12-19 12:51:41.0000000',  0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002,   '2016-03-03 04:11:01.0000000',  '10122374', 117.2100,   '2016-03-03 04:11:01.0000000',  0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002,   '2016-05-27 12:14:45.0000000',  '10122374', 53.5500,    '2016-05-27 12:14:45.0000000',  0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002,   '2016-07-20 06:44:29.0000000',  '10122374', 48.5000,    '2016-07-20 06:44:29.0000000',  0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002,   '2016-10-18 13:49:00.0000000',  '10122374', 75.6800,    '2016-10-18 13:49:00.0000000',  0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002,   '2016-11-09 13:37:02.0000000',  '10122374', 68.2400,    '2016-11-09 13:37:02.0000000',  1 UNION ALL

SELECT 1000001, 1002,   '2016-03-03 02:22:09.0000000',  '161GDB1577',   37.1700,    '2015-12-18 06:45:05.0000000',0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002,   '2016-03-03 02:22:18.0000000',  '0392347402',   41.9100,    '2015-12-18 06:45:14.0000000',0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002,   '2016-05-26 14:54:28.0000000',  '161GDB1577',   46.7100,    '2016-05-26 14:54:28.0000000',0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002,   '2016-05-26 14:54:42.0000000',  '0392347402',   54.7100,    '2016-05-26 14:54:42.0000000',0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002,   '2016-07-15 06:34:33.0000000',  '161GDB1577',   52.4800,    '2016-07-15 06:34:33.0000000',0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002,   '2016-07-15 06:34:45.0000000',  '0392347402',   81.7100,    '2016-07-15 06:34:45.0000000',0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002,   '2016-10-17 11:26:45.0000000',  '161GDB1577',   61.6400,    '2016-10-17 11:26:45.0000000',0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002,   '2016-11-09 02:21:17.0000000',  '0392347402',   81.9200,    '2016-10-17 11:26:58.0000000',1  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002,   '2016-11-09 02:21:05.0000000',  '161GDB1577',   78.3500,    '2016-11-09 02:21:05.0000000',1  UNION ALL
SELECT 1000005, 1002,   '2018-11-09 02:21:05.0000000',  '556556GHB',    78.3500,    '2018-11-09 02:21:05.0000000',1
```

Query I tried - unfortunately it is returning the wrong data :

```
SELECT
    BINGID, INDUSID, DTSEARCH,  
    COMP1, LISTPRICE, FROMDT,
    CASE 
       WHEN IsRowActive = 1 
          THEN '9999-12-31' 
          ELSE TO_DATE 
    END AS TO_DATE,
    IsRowActive
FROM 
    @MYTABLE mt
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT  
         MAX(DATEADD(second, -1, FROMDT)) TO_DATE 
     FROM   
         @MYTABLE mt2 
     WHERE   
         mt2.BINGID = mt.BINGID 
         AND mt2.INDUSID = mt.INDUSID 
         AND mt2.FROMDT > mt.FROMDT) oa
WHERE 
    mt.INDUSID = '1002'
```

Expected output

```
  BINGID    INDUSID DTSEARCH    COMP1   LISTPRICE   FROMDT  NEW_TO_DATE IsRowCurrent
1000001 1002    2016-03-03 02:22:09.0000000 161GDB1577  37.1700 2015-12-18 06:45:05.0000000 2016-05-26 14:54:27.0000000 0
1000001 1002    2016-03-03 02:22:18.0000000 0392347402  41.9100 2015-12-18 06:45:14.0000000 2016-05-26 14:54:41.0000000 0
1000001 1002    2016-05-26 14:54:28.0000000 161GDB1577  46.7100 2016-05-26 14:54:28.0000000 2016-07-15 06:34:32.0000000 0
1000001 1002    2016-05-26 14:54:42.0000000 0392347402  54.7100 2016-05-26 14:54:42.0000000 2016-07-15 06:34:44.0000000 0
1000001 1002    2016-07-15 06:34:33.0000000 161GDB1577  52.4800 2016-07-15 06:34:33.0000000 2016-10-17 11:26:44.0000000 0
1000001 1002    2016-07-15 06:34:45.0000000 0392347402  81.7100 2016-07-15 06:34:45.0000000 2016-10-17 11:26:57.0000000 0
1000001 1002    2016-10-17 11:26:45.0000000 161GDB1577  61.6400 2016-10-17 11:26:45.0000000 2016-11-09 02:21:04.0000000 0
1000001 1002    2016-11-09 02:21:17.0000000 0392347402  81.9200 2016-10-17 11:26:58.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000001 1002    2016-11-09 02:21:05.0000000 161GDB1577  78.3500 2016-11-09 02:21:05.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1000005 1002    2018-11-09 02:21:05.0000000 556556GHB   78.3500 2018-11-09 02:21:05.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1002285,    1002,   '2016-03-03 04:10:58.0000000',  '0026PU009163-031', '77.7600',  2015-12-19 12:51:49.0000000'    2016-05-27 12:14:52.0000000'    0
1002285,    1002,   '2016-05-27 12:14:53.0000000',  '0026PU009163-031', '85.2200',  2016-05-27 12:14:53.0000000'    2016-07-20 06:44:36.0000000'    0
1002285,    1002,   '2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000',  '0026PU009163-031', '90.3900',  2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000'    2016-10-18 13:49:09.0000000'    0
1002285,    1002,   '2016-11-09 13:37:13.0000000',  '0026PU009163-031', '131.4500', 2016-10-18 13:49:10.0000000'    9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
1002285,    1002,   '2015-12-19 12:51:41.0000000',  '10122374', 65.1400,    '2015-12-19 12:51:41.0000000',  2016-03-03 04:11:00.0000000',   0
1002285,    1002,   '2016-03-03 04:11:01.0000000',  '10122374', 117.2100,   '2016-03-03 04:11:01.0000000',  2016-05-27 12:14:44.0000000',   0
1002285,    1002,   '2016-05-27 12:14:45.0000000',  '10122374', 53.5500,    '2016-05-27 12:14:45.0000000',  2016-07-20 06:44:28.0000000',   0
1002285,    1002,   '2016-07-20 06:44:29.0000000',  '10122374', 48.5000,    '2016-07-20 06:44:29.0000000',  2016-10-18 13:48:59.0000000',   0
1002285,    1002,   '2016-10-18 13:49:00.0000000',  '10122374', 75.6800,    '2016-10-18 13:49:00.0000000',  2016-11-09 13:37:01.0000000',   0
1002285,    1002,   '2016-11-09 13:37:02.0000000',  '10122374', 68.2400,    '2016-11-09 13:37:02.0000000',  9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Btw: This is a good question! Copy'n'pasteable test scenario, own effort, expected result... +1 from my side

Comment: @Rohini Mathur Expected output require any order by or as it. or i got result but ordering sequnce only miss matched.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Simple and readable solution, Use `CTE` and `Self Join`

```
with cte as  
( 
  SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() over (order by BINGID,INDUSID,DTSEARCH,COMP1,LISTPRICE,FROMDT) 
      as rowno, -- It is good if you have identity column here
      BINGID,
      INDUSID,    
      DTSEARCH,   
      COMP1,  
      LISTPRICE,  
      FROMDT,
      IsRowActive
      FROM @MYTABLE mt 
)
select c1.*,
 CASE WHEN c1.IsRowActive = 1 THEN '9999-12-31' ELSE DATEADD(second, -1, c2.FROMDT) END
 AS TO_DATE
 from cte c1 left join cte c2
 on c1.rowno+1 = c2.rowno
```

Comment: voted. For simple solution try . but still miss match in results.

Comment: check with another sample data listed in below comments.

Comment: `order by BINGID,INDUSID,DTSEARCH,COMP1,LISTPRICE,FROMDT` can't be right.

Comment: Yes but.. Query shows correct result. also mention --- It is good if you have identity column here

Comment: @Munavvar, actually, no. Your query doesn't return expected result. That's why downvote. Hint: there's better be `PARTITION BY` as well.

Answer (score 2):

I really like @Chanukya's answer.  But as you are using 2008 you will cannot use the LEAD function.  Instead, you can use a self-join:

```
-- SQL Server 2008.
SELECT
    c.*,
    CASE c.IsRowActive 
        WHEN 1 THEN '9999-12-31'
        ELSE DATEADD(SECOND, -1, MIN(p.FROMDT))
    END AS TO_DATE
FROM
    @MYTABLE AS c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @MYTABLE AS p       ON  p.BINGID    = c.BINGID
                                            AND p.INDUSID   = c.INDUSID
                                            AND p.FROMDT    > c.FROMDT
GROUP BY
    c.BINGID,
    c.INDUSID,
    c.DTSEARCH,
    c.COMP1,
    c.LISTPRICE,
    c.FROMDT,
    c.IsRowActive
ORDER BY
    c.FROMDT
;
```

The logic is similar to your outer apply, but it should perform better.  This is because there is no [correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).

The sample data presented a small challenge.  Because there are two records with a `FROMDT` of `2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000` you could argue my results are wrong.

Comment: Thank you @VladimirBaranov.  You are right, my attempt was horrible.  Update to fix.  Like your answer, well written.  Easy to follow.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE
(
BINGID  int,
INDUSID int,
DTSEARCH datetime2, 
COMP1 varchar(100),
LISTPRICE numeric(15,5),    
FROMDT  datetime2,
IsRowActive int

)
insert @MYTABLE

SELECT 1002285  ,1002   ,'2016-03-03 04:10:58.0000000', '0026PU009163-031', 77.7600 ,'2015-12-19 12:51:49.0000000', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285  ,1002   ,'2016-05-27 12:14:53.0000000', '0026PU009163-031', 85.2200 ,'2016-05-27 12:14:53.0000000', 0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285  ,1002   ,'2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000', '0026PU009163-031', 90.3900 ,'2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000', 0  UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285  ,1002   ,'2016-11-09 13:37:13.0000000', '0026PU009163-031', 131.4500,'2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000', 1


select BINGID,DTSEARCH,COMP1,LISTPRICE,FROMDT,CASE WHEN IsRowActive = 0 THEN lead(DATEADD(SS,-1,FROMDT)) OVER (ORDER BY FROMDT) ELSE  '9999-12-31' END AS expected_date

FROM @MYTABLE mt
```

output

```
BINGID  DTSEARCH    COMP1   LISTPRICE   FROMDT  expected_date
1002285 2016-03-03 04:10:58.0000000 0026PU009163-031    77.76000    2015-12-19 12:51:49.0000000 2016-05-27 12:14:52.0000000
1002285 2016-05-27 12:14:53.0000000 0026PU009163-031    85.22000    2016-05-27 12:14:53.0000000 2016-07-20 06:44:36.0000000
1002285 2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000 0026PU009163-031    90.39000    2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000 2016-07-20 06:44:36.0000000
1002285 2016-11-09 13:37:13.0000000 0026PU009163-031    131.45000   2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks But This is not giving correct result. The TO_DATE should be 1 sec less than the next FMDT.

Comment: `LEAD` is not available in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: i edited my answer  can u check once ...@RohiniMathur

Comment: then what is correct to keep in order by ..@VladimirBaranov

Comment: I am not very sure whether it is possible in sql........ may some one please share their expertise. Thanks

Comment: yes it is possible in sql server this solution will works perfectly..@RohiniMathur

Comment: Even if we forget that `LEAD` is not available in SQL Server 2008, still `(ORDER BY FROMDT)` is not correct. Hint: there has to be `PARTITION BY` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `MAX` use `TOP(1)` with appropriate `ORDER BY` in the `OUTER APPLY`.

Also, you said that you want to group by `BINGID, INDUSID, COMP1`, so use all of these columns in the `WHERE` clause in the `OUTER APPLY`. Why did you omit `COMP1` in your query?

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @MYTABLE TABLE
(
    BINGID INT,
    INDUSID INT,
    DTSEARCH DATETIME2,
    COMP1 VARCHAR (100),
    LISTPRICE NUMERIC(10,2),
    FROMDT DATETIME2,
    IsRowActive INT
)

INSERT INTO @MYTABLE
SELECT 1002285, 1002, '2016-03-03 04:10:58', '0026PU009163-031',  77.7600, '2015-12-19 12:51:49', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002, '2016-05-27 12:14:53', '0026PU009163-031',  85.2200, '2016-05-27 12:14:53', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002, '2016-07-20 06:44:37', '0026PU009163-031',  90.3900, '2016-07-20 06:44:37', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002, '2016-11-09 13:37:13', '0026PU009163-031', 131.4500, '2016-10-18 13:49:10', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002, '2015-12-19 12:51:41', '10122374',          65.1400, '2015-12-19 12:51:41', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002, '2016-03-03 04:11:01', '10122374',         117.2100, '2016-03-03 04:11:01', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002, '2016-05-27 12:14:45', '10122374',          53.5500, '2016-05-27 12:14:45', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002, '2016-07-20 06:44:29', '10122374',          48.5000, '2016-07-20 06:44:29', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002, '2016-10-18 13:49:00', '10122374',          75.6800, '2016-10-18 13:49:00', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1002285, 1002, '2016-11-09 13:37:02', '10122374',          68.2400, '2016-11-09 13:37:02', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002, '2016-03-03 02:22:09', '161GDB1577',        37.1700, '2015-12-18 06:45:05', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002, '2016-03-03 02:22:18', '0392347402',        41.9100, '2015-12-18 06:45:14', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002, '2016-05-26 14:54:28', '161GDB1577',        46.7100, '2016-05-26 14:54:28', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002, '2016-05-26 14:54:42', '0392347402',        54.7100, '2016-05-26 14:54:42', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002, '2016-07-15 06:34:33', '161GDB1577',        52.4800, '2016-07-15 06:34:33', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002, '2016-07-15 06:34:45', '0392347402',        81.7100, '2016-07-15 06:34:45', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002, '2016-10-17 11:26:45', '161GDB1577',        61.6400, '2016-10-17 11:26:45', 0 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002, '2016-11-09 02:21:17', '0392347402',        81.9200, '2016-10-17 11:26:58', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000001, 1002, '2016-11-09 02:21:05', '161GDB1577',        78.3500, '2016-11-09 02:21:05', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1000005, 1002, '2018-11-09 02:21:05', '556556GHB',         78.3500, '2018-11-09 02:21:05', 1
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    BINGID,
    INDUSID,
    DTSEARCH,
    COMP1,
    LISTPRICE,
    FROMDT,
    CASE WHEN IsRowActive = 1 THEN '9999-12-31' ELSE oa.TO_DATE END AS TO_DATE,
    IsRowActive
FROM
    @MYTABLE AS mt
    OUTER APPLY 
    (   
        SELECT TOP(1) DATEADD(second, -1, FROMDT) AS TO_DATE
        FROM @MYTABLE AS mt2
        WHERE
            mt2.BINGID = mt.BINGID 
            AND mt2.INDUSID = mt.INDUSID 
            AND mt2.COMP1 = mt.COMP1
            AND mt2.FROMDT > mt.FROMDT
        ORDER BY mt2.FROMDT
    ) AS oa
WHERE
    mt.INDUSID = '1002'
ORDER BY BINGID, INDUSID, COMP1, FROMDT;
```

**Result**

```
+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------+
| BINGID  | INDUSID |          DTSEARCH           |      COMP1       | LISTPRICE |           FROMDT            |           TO_DATE           | IsRowActive |
+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------+
| 1000001 |    1002 | 2016-03-03 02:22:18.0000000 | 0392347402       | 41.91     | 2015-12-18 06:45:14.0000000 | 2016-05-26 14:54:41.0000000 |           0 |
| 1000001 |    1002 | 2016-05-26 14:54:42.0000000 | 0392347402       | 54.71     | 2016-05-26 14:54:42.0000000 | 2016-07-15 06:34:44.0000000 |           0 |
| 1000001 |    1002 | 2016-07-15 06:34:45.0000000 | 0392347402       | 81.71     | 2016-07-15 06:34:45.0000000 | 2016-10-17 11:26:57.0000000 |           0 |
| 1000001 |    1002 | 2016-11-09 02:21:17.0000000 | 0392347402       | 81.92     | 2016-10-17 11:26:58.0000000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 |           1 |
| 1000001 |    1002 | 2016-03-03 02:22:09.0000000 | 161GDB1577       | 37.17     | 2015-12-18 06:45:05.0000000 | 2016-05-26 14:54:27.0000000 |           0 |
| 1000001 |    1002 | 2016-05-26 14:54:28.0000000 | 161GDB1577       | 46.71     | 2016-05-26 14:54:28.0000000 | 2016-07-15 06:34:32.0000000 |           0 |
| 1000001 |    1002 | 2016-07-15 06:34:33.0000000 | 161GDB1577       | 52.48     | 2016-07-15 06:34:33.0000000 | 2016-10-17 11:26:44.0000000 |           0 |
| 1000001 |    1002 | 2016-10-17 11:26:45.0000000 | 161GDB1577       | 61.64     | 2016-10-17 11:26:45.0000000 | 2016-11-09 02:21:04.0000000 |           0 |
| 1000001 |    1002 | 2016-11-09 02:21:05.0000000 | 161GDB1577       | 78.35     | 2016-11-09 02:21:05.0000000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 |           1 |
| 1000005 |    1002 | 2018-11-09 02:21:05.0000000 | 556556GHB        | 78.35     | 2018-11-09 02:21:05.0000000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 |           1 |
| 1002285 |    1002 | 2016-03-03 04:10:58.0000000 | 0026PU009163-031 | 77.76     | 2015-12-19 12:51:49.0000000 | 2016-05-27 12:14:52.0000000 |           0 |
| 1002285 |    1002 | 2016-05-27 12:14:53.0000000 | 0026PU009163-031 | 85.22     | 2016-05-27 12:14:53.0000000 | 2016-07-20 06:44:36.0000000 |           0 |
| 1002285 |    1002 | 2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000 | 0026PU009163-031 | 90.39     | 2016-07-20 06:44:37.0000000 | 2016-10-18 13:49:09.0000000 |           0 |
| 1002285 |    1002 | 2016-11-09 13:37:13.0000000 | 0026PU009163-031 | 131.45    | 2016-10-18 13:49:10.0000000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 |           1 |
| 1002285 |    1002 | 2015-12-19 12:51:41.0000000 | 10122374         | 65.14     | 2015-12-19 12:51:41.0000000 | 2016-03-03 04:11:00.0000000 |           0 |
| 1002285 |    1002 | 2016-03-03 04:11:01.0000000 | 10122374         | 117.21    | 2016-03-03 04:11:01.0000000 | 2016-05-27 12:14:44.0000000 |           0 |
| 1002285 |    1002 | 2016-05-27 12:14:45.0000000 | 10122374         | 53.55     | 2016-05-27 12:14:45.0000000 | 2016-07-20 06:44:28.0000000 |           0 |
| 1002285 |    1002 | 2016-07-20 06:44:29.0000000 | 10122374         | 48.50     | 2016-07-20 06:44:29.0000000 | 2016-10-18 13:48:59.0000000 |           0 |
| 1002285 |    1002 | 2016-10-18 13:49:00.0000000 | 10122374         | 75.68     | 2016-10-18 13:49:00.0000000 | 2016-11-09 13:37:01.0000000 |           0 |
| 1002285 |    1002 | 2016-11-09 13:37:02.0000000 | 10122374         | 68.24     | 2016-11-09 13:37:02.0000000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 |           1 |
+---------+---------+-----------------------------+------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks but i am looking to have value as " 2016-07-20 06:44:36.0000000" in the Third TO_DATE instead of NULL.

Comment: @RohiniMathur, please explain what logic should be there, if there is no "next" row.

Comment: When there is no next row Than It did the Calculation From The Column "IsRowActive = 1" So Calculation will be done on FROMDT column where TO_DATE = 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000

Comment: @RohiniMathur, if you want to have some value in the `TO_DATE` when `FROMDT` has exactly the same value in two rows, then you need to define unambiguous order for these rows. Quite often people use unique row ID in addition to timestamp, if timestamps can have duplicates. Does you table have such ID? At the moment, there is no row that has `FROMDT` that is larger than `2016-07-20 06:44:37`, so "next" row is undefined.

Comment: Thanks........ you are absolutely right Vladimir. i am changing the table structure.

Comment: Hello Techie, may some one please help me on this critical scenario. i have edited the question to include more real data pattern. Thanks a lot

Comment: @RohiniMathur, as far as I can tell, the query in my answer returns the same results as your expected output in the updated question. The order of rows is different, but values are the same, so just put whatever `ORDER BY` you need. For your own help, format the table with the expected result in the question nicely, reorder rows by `BINGID, INDUSID, COMP1, FROMDT`, so that it becomes clear what is going after what and you'll see it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Using CTE + Joins :

Finally, Solution is here.
Result Data is finally accurate as per your requirement also you can change sequence using order by [column name].

Code :

```
      with cte as  
                ( 
                      SELECT 
                      ROW_NUMBER( ) OVER ( partition by  COMP1 ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
                      rowno,
                      BINGID,
                      INDUSID,    
                      DTSEARCH,   
                      COMP1,  
                      LISTPRICE,  
                      FROMDT,
                      IsRowActive
                      FROM @MYTABLE mt 
                )
                select c1.BINGID,c1.INDUSID, c1.DTSEARCH,  c1.COMP1, c1.LISTPRICE, c1.FROMDT, c1.IsRowActive,
                CASE WHEN c1.IsRowActive = 1 THEN '9999-12-31' ELSE case when ( c2.rowno is null ) THEN '9999-12-31' 
                else DATEADD(second, -1, coalesce(c2.FROMDT,'9999-12-31') ) End END
                AS TO_DATE
                from  cte c1   left join cte c2 
                on c1.rowno+1= c2.rowno and c1.COMP1=c2.COMP1

                order by c1.BINGID,DTSEARCH
```

also check [Demo](http://rextester.com/VXM21177).

Comment: Sorry Mr. Bhosale. This is not giving correct result. 2 errors were there, 1st: table have only 2000 records but in output it is giving 5000 records, 2nd: its giving 9999-12-31 00:00:00.0000000 for even IsRowActive='0'

Comment: may i expand the sample data with expected output

Comment: Added some more sample data.

Comment: it means COMP1 values changes.You want separate result according to 'COMP1'
and To_date must be next FROMDT of respected COMP1 group whether sRowActive='1' or '0'. Is it correct ?
what should be 'To_date' for last record which IsRowActive='1'  ?

Comment: Bhosale: absolutely you are right. the last To_date should be 9999-12-31.